# Can you change the sensitivity of UIScrollView scrolling?

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, uiscrollview

Using the Apple's PageControl sample code I've managed to put several UIWebViews side-by-side, and I'm able to swipe left and right in order to get to each web view.

I can also scroll up/down to scroll within each web view. However, I have to move my finger very precisely along the y-axis to get the webview to scroll up/down - otherwise it will slide left or right and show a neighbouring view.

Is there a way to reduce the sensitivity of the left/right scrolling (or increase the sensitivity of the up/down)? Or is there another technique I should be using?

Answer (score 2):

It might be a bit elaborate, but try checking if the UIWebView's scrolling property is true, if it's true, disable scrolling on the UIScrollView until the web view isn't scrolling anymore?

Comment: That sounds like a possible way. But is there a way to detect if a UIWebView is scrolling?

Comment: Hmm... not without exposing its UIScrollView... which Apple won't allow. Sorry, I thought the scroll view methods were exposed on UIWebView, it appears they're not.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the property `pagingEnabled = YES` or `directionalLockEnabled = YES` on your UIScrollView.  It won't be perfect, but it will certainly help.

**pagingEnabled documentation**

> If the value of this property is YES,
>   the scroll view stops on multiples of
>   the view bounds when the user scrolls.
>   The default value is NO

**directionalLockEnabled documentation**

> If this property is NO, scrolling is
>   permitted in both horizontal and
>   vertical directions. If this property
>   is YES and the user begins dragging in
>   one general direction (horizontally or
>   vertically), the scroll view disables
>   scrolling in the other direction. If
>   the drag direction is diagonal, then
>   scrolling will not be locked and the
>   user can drag in any direction until
>   the drag completes. The default value
>   is NO